# Заполонить что-либо собою

Tags: грамотная-речь

С грамматической точки зрения, как правильно будет сказать: "Мысли Романа заполонили сотни вопросов" (то есть мысли наполнились вопросами) или "Сотни вопросов заполонили мысли Романа"? А может, оба варианта правильны? Просто, конечно, первый вариант в принципе понять можно, но, читая, постоянно приходит на ум, что МЫСЛИ наполняют вопросы… так, возможен ли первый вариант вообще?

Comment: Чего вы вообще не ставите лайки и галочки за ответы? Больше бы людей отвечало. А так - отвечать совсем не интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже после упрощения эта фраза режет мне глаз. Вот, как мне кажется, более гармоничные варианты:

"Романа одолевали сотни вопросов."

"Роман был в смятении и мыслями перескакивал с одного вопроса на другой."

"Мысли Романа метались и перескакивали от одного вопроса к другому, к третьему, к сотому."

Answer (score 1):

Стилистически — все плохо. Не надо здесь глагол "заполонить" использовать. Лучше "овладели" или "заняли".

***Сотни вопросов овладели мыслями Романа.***

Заодно и двусмысленность убирается.

Но если говорить о грамматике, то в подобных случаях грамматической омонимии принято трактовать так, что подлежащее предшествует сказуемому, а прямое дополнение идет после него. "Сорняки угнетали полезные растения" — не наоборот. То есть ваш второй вариант грамматически более верный.